# Root finding for stochastic function with discrete sample space

Tags: algorithms

I have a series $x_n$, for $n=1,\dots,N$, with $x_0<0$ and and $x_N>0$.  For each $n$, I can test whether $x_n>0$, which gives me a probability $p$ that $x_n>0$.  If $p\in\{0,1\}$, I would use a the bisection method.  How can I extend this to the probabilistic case?

This question is similar to [Root finding for stochastic function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93099/root-finding-for-stochastic-function/93638#93638), which deals with finding roots in a continuous interval (say [0,1]).